# Docker Permission Denied through Jenkins pipeline

Tags: docker, ubuntu, jenkins, dockerfile, permission-denied

I have installed Docker using apt in ubuntu
`sudo apt install docker.io`
And have installed JDK 17 as well as Jenkins.

So Whenever I try to build a docker image using Dockerfile through Jenkins which is in a different location than my build work space , it throws me an error stating

`unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /home/ubuntu/github_folder: permission denied`

The Image gets build if I use the dockerfile from the same workspace i.e my GitHub folder which includes a Dockerfile.

I have tried to insert jenkins user in all the possible groups

```
sudo usermod -a -G docker jenkins 
sudo usermod -a -G jenkins ubuntu
sudo usermod -a -G jenkins root
```

Still getting the same permission denied error.

I even checked with my dockerfile which is present in the location, and it defines "Dockerfile" with no extensions.

My pipeline :

```
pipeline {
    agent any

    stages {
        stage("Checkout Code") {
            steps {
                cleanWs()
                git branch: 'main', url: '<githublink>'
            }
        }

        stage("Build Docker Image") {
            steps {
                script {
                    sh 'docker build -t uditdevadiiga/chatbot -f /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/<path>/Dockerfile .'
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```